# Oracle Apex Dynamic Action not capturing the value change to Page Item

Tags: oracle-apex

My requirement is to conditionally show a popup when the process is completed. for instance, update the employees in a department and a location. So from the Apex I select one employee and click on submit to update some x column. Now after the update is completed, I want to show a popup only if there are any other employees left in the same department and location, if none left no popup is required.

My approach was, 
1)  I created a **pageitem1**, assigning a flag 'Y' once the process is successfully completed and if there are any further employees left for criteria.
2) Create a DA on the pageitem with the Event - **Change** Client Side condition as 
   TYPE **Item = value**
   ITEM **pageitem1**
   VALUE **Y**
3) Tried the True Action under the above DA in different ways

- Show and Java script to show alert using alert function

  alert('Check Other Pools');
- Notification as alert

after debugging the pageitem value, I understood that the event of change is not captured when the pageitem is assigned inside the PL/SQL block. Is this correct? If so what can be done to achieve this?

Another option I tried is htp.prn with the below code inside the PL/SQL block

```
htp.prn('<script language="Javascript">');
htp.prn('alert(''Check other employees'');');
htp.prn('</script>');
```

Appreciate your in reading this lengthy explanation and trying to provide a solution. I am pretty new to Apex and apologize if the wording is not clear.

Edit: Apex v5.1

Comment: If you submit the page and the page is loaded again, then your DA in a change item will not work. In this case try to change your DA to "On page load".

Comment: @romeuBraga, Thanks for the response, I have another step ON SUBMIT, it is after processing the current page will redirect to its parent page. But what I don't understand is atleast htp.prn should work for me.

Comment: Sorry, i can't help with that. As far as i now htp.* functions works when the page is loading. In this case the page is already loaded. Create a process to do what you need >> set a value of an item to something to use in your DA to show your alert >> create a DA in a page load >> use that item to decide if an alert should be showed or not. >> clean this item